# Mule 3.3.1 Increment count in incoming header

Tags: variables, mule, increment

In Mule 3.3.1, how do I increment a value of an Inbound property named "count" and pass it as an Outbound property?

I tried

```
<set-variable variableName="count" value="#[header:count?]"/>

<!-- SOME FLOW........
...... -->
<!-- Inside exception strategy -->
<message-properties-transformer> 
    <add-message-property key="count" value="#[variable:count + 1]" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

but it errors with "Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:count - 1" returned null but a value was required".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MEL:

```
<set-property propertyName="count"
              value="#[message.inboundProperties.count + 1]" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean we cannot increment values in Variables....or something like #[header:count + 1] ?

Comment: You can absolutely increment values in variables, but it wasn't what you asked :) If `count` would be a variable name, you would increment it with `<set-variable variableName="cound" value="#[count + 1]">`

Comment: HA HA. Ok. But I'm looking for a little variation. Let's say I have a value in variable "count". I would like set an outbound property with the value of this variable + something. like `<set-property properyName="count" value="#[count + 1]"/>`?

Comment: Yes, totally, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Wonder what I had done earlier...was getting some null exception. It works fine. If only you could please help me with "<jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime > #[XXX]"/>" :) :) Thanks!

Comment: I suspect a bug or missing feature for the selector issue.

Comment: Please note that if in a VM, the counter value is lost. :/

Comment: @Adnama What do you mean?

Comment: From my experience with mule, in some cases the VM looses the values of variables.

Comment: Properly scoped properties should never be lost in Mule, I reckon you were not storing your properties in the outbound scope when sending the message through VM.